# Angular: passing data to directive during compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

Trying to do something like this:

```
var data = {some: 'data'}

var subcomponent = $compile('<div component-' + componentName + ' ng-model="'+data+'"></div>')($scope);

$element.find('.container').html( subcomponent[0] );
```

I get error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object]] starting at [Object]]
```

**Trying to get this data to the `link` scope. Is there a way I should be going about passing the data to the directive scope?**

Comment: `ng-model="'+data.some+'"`?????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ng-model` expression must be a property whose value can be set. So you would need to do something like.

```
$scope.data = {some: 'data'};// Set a property on the scope

/*Bind data to the ng-model*/
var subcomponent = $compile('<div component-' + componentName + ' ng-model="data"></div>')($scope);
```

In your case you are trying to add an object to the string which will convert the object to its string representation i.e `[object Object]`. So what you need is to set a property name (existing/non-existing) on the scope.

Comment: Been trying to figure this out all morning. I didn't realize that `$compile` was looking for  `$scope.data` rather than just `data`. Thanks!